# MySQL get first existing row with value OR get another ordered

Tags: php, mysql

I need to write mysql query for table like this:

```
id | product_id | version | status 
 1 | 1          | 1       | 0
 2 | 1          | 2       | 1
 3 | 1          | 3       | 0
 4 | 2          | 9       | 0
 5 | 2          | 10      | 0
```

I need to get rows (unique for product_id - one for each product_id) but:
-if there is row for product_id with status=1 - grab it
-it there is no row as described get row with higher value or version

So for described table result should be

```
id | product_id | version | status 
 2 | 1          | 2       | 1
 5 | 2          | 10      | 0
```

My only idea is to get rows with status 1, and then make second query using WHERE product_id NOT IN and then order by version DESC and GROUP BY product_id

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Can join back to the table in this case

```
SELECT p1.id, p1.product_id, p1.version, p1.status FROM products p1
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(version) AS version FROM products p2
   ) p2 ON p1.version = p2.version OR p1.status = 1
GROUP BY p1.product_id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/325a85/30)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with a `UNION`

```
select myTable.id, product_id, version, status from myTable
where id in(select id from myTable where status > 0) 
union
select myTable.id, product_id, version, status from myTable
join (select max(id) as id from myTable group by product_id) 
as m on m.id = myTable.id 
and product_id  not in(select product_id from myTable where status > 0 )
```